# AuthFailure with Net::Amazon::EC2

Tags: perl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using the example from Net::Amazon::EC2 to connect to my EC2 instances.
I have set the correct AWSAccessKeyId and SecretAccessKey. No more changes.

Code:

```
 my $ec2 = Net::Amazon::EC2->new(
        AWSAccessKeyId    => 'abcdef',
        SecretAccessKey   => 'defghijklmnopq',
        signature_version => 4,
 );
```

However, I get the follwing error:

```
[AuthFailure] Authorization header or parameters are not formatted correctly.
```

Any idea what I should do different?

Thanks

Comment: For one thing, use correctly formatted authorization header or parameters. Either that or show some code.

Comment: What are you passing to the constructor for `signature_version`?  Are you using the latest version of the module? Does `debug => 1` provide any more info?  Was it working, then stopped, or is this your first attempt?

Comment: Added the code. It was not working. It failed straight away. signature_version = 4.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I followed the perl Net::Amazon::EC2 documentation (which said to include signature_version => 4).
I commented this out (which falls back to the default value of 2), and it all worked.